# How get the horizontal-size from the DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I have a complex web page using React components, and am trying to convert the page from a static layout to a more responsive, resizable layout. However, I keep running into limitations with React, and am wondering if there's a standard pattern for handling these issues. In my specific case, I have a component that renders as a div with display:table-cell and width:auto.

Unfortunately, I cannot query with width of my component, because you can't compute the size of an element unless it's actually placed in the DOM (which has the full context with which to deduce the actual rendered width). Besides using this for things like relative mouse positioning, I also need this to properly set width attributes on SVG elements within the component.

In addition, when the window resizes, how do I communicate size changes from one component to another during setup? We're doing all of our 3rd-party SVG rendering in shouldComponentUpdate, but you cannot set state or properties on yourself or other child components within that method.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this problem using React?

Answer (score 1):

The method of lifecycle you probably want is **componentDidMount**
The elements have already been placed in the DOM and you can get information about them from the component's refs.

Example:

```
var Container = React.createComponent({

  componentDidMount: function () {
    var width = this.refs.svg.getDOMNode().offsetWidth;
  },

  render: function () {
    <svg ref="svg" />
  }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

In componentDidMount you can get the window.width or ReactDom.findDOMNode(this).width. Then use the width in state and pass as a prop as needed. You can also set a listener for the resize event.